# adding values to database using ajax without reloading or redirect the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add records into the database table without reloading the page, I am using `ajax` in my case eventually got a response(`201`) from the server(`alert("Error occurred !")`). I just messed up with this code from the last couple of hours but didn't find the hit where I am getting wrong.

**records.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Insert data in MySQL database using Ajax</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin: auto;width: 60%;">
 <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="success" style="display:none;">
   <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
 </div>
 <form id="fupForm" name="form1" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="email">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="pwd">Email:</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="pwd">Phone:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" name="phone">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" >
   <label for="pwd">City:</label>
   <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
    <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <input type="button" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save to database" id="butsave">
 </form>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#butsave').on('click', function() {
  $("#butsave").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var phone = $('#phone').val();
  var city = $('#city').val();
  if(name!="" && email!="" && phone!="" && city!=""){
   $.ajax({
    url: "input.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
     name: name,
     email: email,
     phone: phone,
     city: city    
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(dataResult){
     var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
     if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
      $("#butsave").removeAttr("disabled");
      $('#fupForm').find('input:text').val('');
      $("#success").show();
      $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');       
     }
     else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
        alert("Error occured !");
     }
     
    }
   });
  }
  else{
   alert('Please fill all the field !');
  }
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**input.php**

```
<?php
include "mysqli_connect.php";
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `bulk`( `name`, `email`, `phone`, `city`) 
    VALUES ('$name','$email','$phone','$city')";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>200));
    } 
    else {
        echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201));
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**Table structure:**
[image: here]

Comment: what have you tried so far to solve possible issue(s) - how have you gone about debugging your code?

Comment: I checked whether data is coming or not into the input.php, I guess the mistake is in records.html file in ajax code

Comment: check if the connection to the database is successful: `if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo mysqli_connect_error();
}`

Comment: Side note, you disable the button. You then check to see if the form is valid, if not, you tell them to fix it. The button is disabled.... not sure how they can try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `datatype:"JSON"` in your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "input.php",
    datatype: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        city: city              
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(dataResult){
        var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
        alert(dataResult);
        if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
            $("#butsave").removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#fupForm').find('input:text').val('');
            $("#success").show();
            $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');                        
        }
        else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
           alert("Error occured !");
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data: {
    'name': name,
    'email': email,
    'phone': phone,
    'city': city                
    }
```

Try this and if it doesn't work do a `print_r` of the `$name` variables to see if they are filled incorrectly.

Comment: I cant be print_r because input.php is running in the background when i hit the button

Comment: Is id field autoincrement type?

Answer (score 1):

In `input.php`, check whether the data is coming or not:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['city']))
{
   /// your insert code
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting, I apply your code and Now I guess data is not coming to input.php page from records.html

Comment: in ajax check whether the value is coming or not  like alert(name)